# How to recommend users content based on their interactions in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, machine-learning

A question that has been bugging me quite recently is how to create a recommendation system. A feature that I'm implementing in my website I'm currently developing is something called Communities - which are what people can create an chat with different people in.

I've been thinking about the number of messages, users, and the privacy of the Community to recommend users Communities when they're logged out, and to recommend users Communities - when they're logged in - based on the number of messages and users in the Community, or based on the Communities they've participated in -- in the past.

The main question is: how to implement such feature?

Comment: This is too broad for SO, which is really meant for specific coding issues. Maybe you'd have more luck on [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thanks, I'll post this on the software engineering forum instead.